# Should Jenkins be run inside development/deployment environment or on standalone box

Tags: jenkins

I am using Vagrant to provide a 'synchronised' and standardised development/test/uat/staging and production environments.

I am now looking at how to standardise my CI build process. I like the look of Jenkins but I am confused as to what the best way to deploy it is. Should I have it deployed in a stand-alone CI box or install it on all the various environments?

I guess I am a little confused here. Any help much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is a stand-alone CI server shared by the development team. This common server (at a well known URL) provides the development dashboard for a team and the only authorized way to publish into the release repository (Developers not allowed to publish directly)

You could go for extra credit and also setup an instance of [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) which in my opinion is much better suited as a development dashboard, providing a richer set of metrics and also serves as a historicial record for development.

Finally Jenkins is so simple to setup, there is nothing stopping developers from running their own instances. I find that with Sonar it matters less and less where a build is actually run, once the release credentials are properly controlled. In fact this attitude is important as it prevents the build server from turning into a delicate [snowflake](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SnowflakeServer.html) :-)

## Update

There's a [vagrant plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Vagrant+Plugin) for Jenkins which might prove useful in running your current processes.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely better off running Jenkins as a shared stand-alone server.

**However**, I highly recommend that you set up your builds in such a way that they can be run on each developer's machine locally as well. This is particularly key with unit-tests.

In our setup, we have a shared Jenkins server that executes all of our builds using NAnt. Each developer also has NAnt installed and can run the build and unit-test portions of the build freely. Ideally integration tests could also be run, but we're not quite there yet and having them execute on the CI server still gives us that proper feedback even if it takes a little longer to get.